# Remove css bottom attribute on mobile view

Tags: css

I have an element that is attached to the bottom of the screen correctly. using `bottom: 0`

however, when I move into mobile view I still want it roughly the same height but I want to be able to scroll down to view the rest of the element, almost feels like I need to remove the bottom attribute

I'm using media queries but not sure how to get the desired effect I want. coz if I remove `bottom` from the media query, it will just carry on applying it

any ideas?

Comment: Rather than using a media query to remove the attribute, you should use a media query to only apply the attribute when necessary. If you're still seeing the "wrong" behavior, it's likely not related to this attribute and you'd need to post some code for us to look at.

Comment: fixed with a combination of unset, position and magic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use `media-query`:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp**

See here sizes:https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    yourElement {
           bottom: unset;
    }
}
```